# Visual Studio 2010 + Visual Assist C++: Are there any automated ways to create getters and setters?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, automation, getter-setter, visual-assist

So I am creating a simple class like:

```
class file
{
public:
    boost::filesystem::path path;
    bool is_directory;
    boost::uintmax_t target_size;
    void get(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, boost::shared_ptr<http_response> response);
    void set()
};
```

and I see that if some automated procedure would provide me a dialog and create geters and setters for some of my variables (instead of me just leaving tham to be public or creating each manually ) my code API would look beter, and it would be easier for me to implement thread safty. Is there any command for doing such dirty work in VS2010 or in VA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select class variable and from context menu pick *Refactor (VA X) -> Encapsulate Field*. You can customise the format by modifying *Refactor Encapsulate Field* snippet. You can find more on customising snippets [here](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/vasnippets.asp).

The snippet I personally use yields Java-like accessors with doxygen documentation stubs:

```
//! \return
$end$$SymbolType$ get$GeneratedPropertyName$() const
{ 
    return $SymbolName$;
}
//! \param $SymbolName$
void set$GeneratedPropertyName$($SymbolType$ $SymbolName$) 
{ 
    this->$SymbolName$ = $SymbolName$; 
}
```

Of course it's not perfect, you'll still have to modify results from time to time (adjusting constness, pointers, references), but it case a lot of time.

Alternatively you can create your own custom snippet and run it from context menu *Surround with (VA X)*, but you won't have access to $Symbol*$ variables.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Visual Studio 2010 but in visual assist you have the command '[Encapsulate Field](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/encapsulateField.asp)' iirc the template for this refactoring can be modified like all the other templates. If you need to separate methods to create thread safe and non thread safe accessors you can probably write a separate template that produces the appropriate code